# Bootstrap grid: allocating 2x2 elements to 1x4 in a clockwise order?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to allocate 4 divs in a way that:

in large screen, it would look like:

```
-------------
|  A  |  B  |
-------------
|  D  |  C  |
-------------
```

and in small screen :

```
-----
| A |
-----
| B |
-----
| C |
-----
| D |
-----
```

Is there a way I could achieve this without javascript or flexbox?

Comment: The reason for this: use a [`@media` query](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) to make the distinction between large and small screens, and inside the query for large screens you use flex-box to switch block D and C.

Comment: Well, maybe. But I wanted to do it without any flex-box and I got the answer without one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in to the push & pull classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">A</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12">B</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-push-6 col-sm-12">C</div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-pull-6 col-sm-12">D</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the use of push or pull classes before, but now I get it!

Comment: That's exactly how i felt after i used them for the first time! Felt pointless to me until you start building with mobile first or at least laying out your HTML with mobile in mind first :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes have to create two rows for that and these are the classes used to show according to the device size.

1. lg - for large screens(Large Desktop)
2. md - for medium screens(Medium Screen Desktop)
3. sm - for small screens(Tablets,Ipads)
4. xs - for extra small screens(Mobile Devices)

HTML :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">C</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-xs-12">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer does not resolve the OP's *order* issue.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bootply.com/DADhwYwk1I

Have a look at using multiple classes for your grid layout. See the link above for an example of how I done this. There are other ways of getting this done also. ( on the right hand side of the screen on the link there is a mobile icon. Click that to see what it is like on a portable device.)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">A</div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">B</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">C</div>
   <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-12">D</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [**it would be preferable**](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes